# Getting template derive class's value from base class pointer

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a tool that allows the user to edit glsl's uniform variable value and I need to store all the data in a std::vector.

Since all the variable's value has different variable type(vec2, vec3, vec4, mat2... etc), storing them in a single container is a challenge. I have decided to go with this approach

```
class BaseData
{
    public:
};

template <typename T>
class Data: public BaseData
{
public:

    Data(TypeEnum enumType, T valueIN): value(valueIN), type(enumType)
    {

    }

    T GetValue()
    {
        return value; 
    }

    TypeEnum GetType()
    {
        return type;
    }

private:
    T value;
    TypeEnum type;
};

class Material
{
    Material(std::vector<Base*> valueVec)
    {
        for(auto i : valueVec)
        { 
            switch(i->GetType())
            {
                case BaseColor:
                    SetBaseColor(i->GetValue());//need something like this
                    break;
                case BaseTexture:
                    SetBaseTexture(i->GetValue());//need something like this
                    break;
                case EmissionColor:
                    SetEmissionFactor(i->GetValue());//need something like this
                    break;
                case EmissionTexture:
                    SetEmissionTexture(i->GetValue());//need something like this
                    break;
                case Material_nProps_NormalTexture:
                    SetNormalMap(i->GetValue());//need something like this
            } 
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<BaseData*> uniformValue;

    uniformValue.push_back(new Data(BaseColor, glm::vec4(1,2,3,4)));
    uniformValue.push_back(new Data(BaseTexture, 0));
    uniformValue.push_back(new Data(EmissionColor, glm::vec3(1,1,1)));    
    uniformValue.push_back(new Data(BaseTexture, 1));

    Material PBR(uniformValue);
}
```

but the problem how is, now how do I get *value* from the base pointer without casting it to the correct derive type pointer?

Comment: If you have a limited number of possible types, check [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)  (or `boost::variant` if you do not have a C++17 compiler) and the visitor pattern ([`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)).

Comment: hi @Holt unfortunately only c++98 is allow :(

Comment: Then like Holt said, checkout `boost`.

Comment: I am aware of boost, but again that is not available for my scenerio

Comment: Maybe look into the 'typeid' operator.

Comment: Can't you reverse the logic ? I mean instead of calling `somefunction` on a value you don't know the type, you give to your `Derive` class the function to call and you add a new virtual in your `Base` that will call the function you passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to cast, you could use the command pattern, where each GLSL property class receives a pointer to the Material object and executes the appropriate action. Each command would need access to some internals of Material. The code below illustrates that. (note that everything is public just for simplicity).

```
struct Material; // forward declaration
struct GlslPropertyBase {
    virtual ~GlslPropertyBase() {}
    virtual void Execute(Material* m) = 0;
};

struct Material {
    void SetBaseColor(Vec3 col) { /* Do something */ }
    void SetBaseTexture(GLuint uid) { /* Do something */ }

    Material(std::vector<GlslPropertyBase*> properties) {
        for (GlslPropertyBase* property : properties)
            property->Execute(this);
    }
};

struct GlSlBaseColor : GlslPropertyBase {
    Vec3 color;
    GlSlBaseColor(float r, float g, float b) : color(r, g, b) {}
    void Execute(Material* m) { m->SetBaseColor(color); }
};

struct GlSlBaseTexture : GlslPropertyBase {
    GLuint uid;
    GlSlBaseTexture(GLuint uid) : uid(uid) {}
    void Execute(Material* m) { m->SetBaseTexture(uid); }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<GlslPropertyBase*> properties;
    properties.push_back(new GlSlBaseColor(1, 2, 3));
    properties.push_back(new GlSlBaseTexture(1));

    Material PBR(properties);

    // delete heap objects...
}
```

This is just a simple way (and implementation) to process the heterogeneous glsl properties stored in a single vector, without casting, and probably what @francesco suggested at the end of [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292090/1514936).